# d-band center calculation from GPAW code

Tags: density-of-states, gpaw, d-band

How may I calculate the d-band center of metals using GPAW? In other words, how may I get the ASCII data from a `gpw` file?

Comment: I gave my +1 a long time ago, but have you found an answer to this question yet? Let us know!